# SXA Generate Multilingual Static Error Pages

Tags: sxa

I am using sitecore 9.1 with SXA 1.8 and when i tried to use the feature of generating static error pages in SXA, i found a folder created on the root of the iis site called "ErrorPages" and i found only one page.

I need to know how sxa will be handling the error page in multilingual site?